# Error dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, heap-memory

Creating in Stack doen't generate any error
 Creating in heap dynamically generates Error.

```
   int a;
   cin>>a;
   int B[a];  // OK
   int A[] = new int[a]; // error: variable-sized object 'A' may not be initialized
```

Why second one causes the error?

Comment: `int B[a];` is not legal C++ either. It's a compiler extension.

Comment: @T.C. no error with first one

Comment: `int * A = new int[a];` should be OK.

Comment: @songyuanyao I know that, but why not in STACK?

Comment: Because `new` returns a pointer.

Comment: @AAAser You'll get a warning if you compile in strict conformance mode (`-pedantic`) and an error with MSVC (which doesn't support variable-length arrays).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B[a] is illegal. the array size needs to be known at compile time.
'A' should be of type int* not int[].

```
int* A=new int[a];
```

Comment: What?
   int a;
   cin>>a;
   int B[a];  // OK
   B[1] = 45;
   cout<<B[1]<<endl;
NO PROBLEM! (IDE - CODE::Block)

Comment: @AAAser It is illegal. **It is a compiler extension**. But the main point is that `new` returns a pointer.

Comment: @AAAser I realise C++ is confusing like that, because `int[]` in a function parameter list *is* actually a pointer. But in this context it isn't.